# Init a var in main thread

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

If I init a UIWindow like this:

```
open lazy var whistleWindow: UIWindow = UIWindow()
```

I get an runtime issue:

> UIWindow() must be called from main tread only

[image]

Therefore, I tried to do something like this:

```
open lazy var whistleWindow: UIWindow = {

  var window:UIWindow!

  DispatchQueue.main.sync {
    window = UIWindow()
  }

  return window
}()
```

Sadly I get this error at runtime:

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10497bba4)

What could I do?

Comment: `open lazy var whistleWindow: UIWindow = UIWindow()` compiles and runs without a problem for me here.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Which class is this variable on?  How are you creating the instance of that class?  Why are you creating a `UIWindow` anyway?

Comment: @Paulw11 i think you have a point. I have to be sure when I instance the class i have to do it in the main thread.  I do not why they create a UIWindow, it is not my code... it is from https://github.com/hyperoslo/Whisper.

Comment: @LeoDabus, You are right the code compiles and run, but i get  a "Runtime issue", i think they are new in Xcode 9 [check](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/xcode_9/xcode_9.html).  The desired behavior was not to get the "RunTime issue". You can replicate using [this](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Whisper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open lazy var whistleWindow: UIWindow = {
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        return UIWindow()
    }
}()
```

Comment: this is not always the approach since it blocks the entire main queue, be careful.